# ASP.net MVC and REACT

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two JSX files(one component in each file) in my MVC Project. I want to import "Comment" component. I just moved to MVC React. earlier I used this,

```
import Comment from './Comment'
```

and above code works, but now I get the error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

Post.jsx

```
class Post extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Comment />
            </div>
            )
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(
    <Post />,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Comment.jsx

```
export default class Comment extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                I am a Comment
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Importing component like that needs a transpiler like babel...

Comment: on what page are you calling the import ??

Comment: You aren't bundling the app with babel. Can you post your webpack.config.js file?